# Will installing Debian firmware affect Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, amd-radeon, firmware, display-driver, debian-stretch

My PC dual-boots both Windows 10 and Debian. I would like to install `firmware-linux-nonfree` so that I can use 3D acceleration and change the screen brightness from Debian.

I'm following the instructions from [AtiHowTo](https://wiki.debian.org/AtiHowTo#Firmware) where it says that I should install the driver firmware/microcode (`firmware-linux-nonfree`) because

> "Without this package installed, poor 2D/3D performance in the radeon
>   driver is commonly experienced."

This means the firmware package affects the interface to the graphics card, but I don't know the specifics of how it's implemented in Debian.

However, I am concerned that flashing the firmware will affect the performance or even the operation of the Windows drivers. **How will Windows 10 respond to this change**, and how should I prepare to mitigate the effects of this?

Specific Details (feel free to comment if more are required)

- PC model: HP 15-g094sa Notebook PC
- Graphics Card: AMD Radeon R5
- Windows minor version: v1607
- Debian major version: Stretch

Edit: I am now planning to make [a backup of the firmware](http:////unix.stackexchange.com/questions/423385/), before trying the package to see what happens. Hopefully, that should mean that I can answer this question myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you already have an answer at Unix SE. I’ll repeat the facts quickly:

- This type of firmware is saved in volatile memory (no flashing involved)
- It will typically not affect Windows at all
- You cannot backup anything because it isn’t there in the first place

In case the firmware interferes with Windows drivers, simply shut down completely before switching operating systems. Without power, the volatile memory’s contents are lost.

Think about it: Would you even need the firmware if it were actually “installed” on the device?